# Omniauth devise Authentication failure! csrf_detected:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I got the  `Authentication failure! csrf_detected:`  so that I couldn't login with omniauth.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-devise-and-omniauth-for-your-rails-application)

and I found similar issue [here](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/73),

But there are no luck for my problem till now.

Any idea for fixing the error ? Thanks

```
E, [2015-06-27T10:40:06.028200 #18798] ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
```

## Gems

```
  * devise (3.5.0)
  * omniauth (1.2.2)
  * omniauth-facebook (2.0.0)
  * omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1)
```

## /app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception
-
+  before_action :authenticate_user!
```

## /app/models/user.rb

```
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
+         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
+  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
+    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
+      binding.pry
+      user.provider = auth.provider
+      user.uid = auth.uid
+      user.email = auth.info.email
+      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
+    end
+  end
+
```

## /config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
+Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
+  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
+   :scope => 'email'
+end
```

## Error log from console (how to trace it?)

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQDZC-Ny2PI-UwunCNi29mx4YGKT&state=cf896d3decffe2a7a664315e050a1165a290477542ff7d33" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-27 10:40:05 +0800
I, [2015-06-27T10:40:05.255832 #18798]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
I, [2015-06-27T10:40:06.028051 #18798]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2015-06-27T10:40:06.028200 #18798] ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
Processing by CallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQDZC-Ny2PI-UwunCNi29mx4YGKTuHDeP2X2X-leywO14gr_iHLvXxX1LpV5WteUrQHpX-uc0Z01wcjy4XHA9CBkZeSo4qRb7jXdvPLfQl6mgwbMrFuQb1_55KughvtMWMlZ_7YEhtiLoEZH_2EvGXLbuKkUq", "state"=>"cf896d3decffe2a7a663"}
```

## routes

```
+  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks" }
```

Comment: were you able to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you also asked [this question](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/208) on the [Omniauth Facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/) Github Repo. It didn't look like there was a solid answer there either.

[@dmcbrayer](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/208#issuecomment-140139902) did suggest changing your initializer to look like:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
   :scope => 'email',
   :info_fields => 'email'
end
```

This was due to an API change on facebook side which required you to explicitly ask for `info_fields`.

The maintainer [@mkdynamic](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/208#issuecomment-151385791) also wanted you to verify whether it was fixed in a newer version (3.0.0 at the time).